# Jquery show and hide conflicting

Tags: jquery, html, css, hover, jquery-hover

I have created some Jquery combined with css to do the following

1) when hovered over image the image fades and shows pink bg

2) when hovered shows the logo

the problem is the logo is showing on all when I duplicate the classes

Can anybody help.

Please see [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BC4eY/1434/)

```
$(".portfolio-home").hover(function () {
    $(this).find(".show-logo").show();
}, function () {
    $(this).find(".show-logo").hide();
})
```

Comment: You can do this without any sort of jquery just using css.

Answer (score 4):

It's just the `li` missing on your selector. Otherwise it will search for all elements with class `show-logo` within the `ul`.

```
$(".portfolio-home li").hover(function () {
    $(this).find(".show-logo").show();
}, function () {
    $(this).find(".show-logo").hide();
})
```

Demo :http://jsfiddle.net/BC4eY/1435/

Comment: @JoshPowell Hahaha :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method for this.

```
$(".portfolio-home").on( 'hover', 'li', function () {
    $(this).find(".show-logo").show();
}, function () {
    $(this).find(".show-logo").hide();
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is without using any sort of Jquery and just CSS. Dont overthink this, its easier than you think. Have an awesome one!

```
.portfolio-home ul li:hover{
background: grey;
opacity: 0.5;
}
ul.portfolio-home li:hover img.show-logo{
position: absolute;
display: block;
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/cornelas/BC4eY/1442/)